# Unterschied zwischen »Abfolge« und »Reihenfolge«

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonym

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern „die Abfolge“ und „die Reihenfolge“?

Beide werden auf Englisch mit "sequence/order" übersetzt.

Sind sie Synonyme?
Wenn ja, kann man sie austauschen?

Answer (score 5):

**Reihenfolge** bezieht sich allgemein auf eine Sortierung von Elementen.
Das kann örtlich (vor/hinter, über/unter), zeitlich (vor/nach), oder nach sonstigen Kriterien (größer/kleiner, älter/jünger) gemeint sein

Eine **Abfolge** verstehe ich nur als die zeitliche Sortierung. Zum Beispiel von Ereignissen, die in einer bestimmten Weise hintereinander passieren.

Man kann also nicht immer Reihenfolge durch Abfolge ersetzen. Andersherum wäre es inhaltlich denkbar, wobei auf den Satzbau geachtet werden muss. Die Wörter einfach austauschen funktioniert nicht grundsätzlich, sie sind keine hundertprozentigen Synonyme.

#### Ein Beispiel

Die verschiedenen Sendungen die ein Fernsehsender an einem Tag zeigt, stehen in der Programmübersicht in einer bestimmten **Reihenfolge**.
Bei den Sendungen steht zwar die Zeit, aber die Tatsache dass die Sendungen dort stehen ist noch keine zeitliche Aktion. Deshalb kann man hier nicht Abfolge sagen.
Die **Abfolge** ist der Vorgang, diese Sendungen hintereinander auszustrahlen. Hier ist der zeitliche Aspekt vorhanden, denn vorhin kam Sendung A, jetzt gerade läuft Sendung B und später wird Sendung C gezeigt.

#### Noch ein Beispiel

Auf einer Liste stehen verschiedene Namen von Personen, die bei einer Veranstaltung auf die Bühne kommen und dort einen Preis erhalten. Die Sortierung in der die Namen da stehen, ist die **Reihenfolge**.
Eine **Abfolge** wird dann daraus, wenn jemand die Namen auf der Liste in dieser Reihenfolge vorliest und die Personen dann einer nach dem anderen die Bühne betritt.

#### ein drittes Beispiel

Eine Stadtführung besteht aus einem Frühstück, dann einem Vortrag, danach einem Rundgang durch die Stadt, dem Mittagessen und zum Abschluss der Besichtigung des Museums.
Die Auflistung der Aktivitäten ist die **Reihenfolge**.
Bei der Durchführung kann man sagen, die Aktivitäten finden in dieser Reihenfolge statt, oder die Abfolge der Aktivitäten ist Frühstück, Vortrag, Rundgang...

Comment: Im 3. Beispiel: "... die Aktivitäten finden in dieser Abfolge statt" bzw. "die Reihenfolge d. Aktivitäten ist ..." funktioniert genauso. Ein Unterschied im Satzbau wird nicht deutlich.

Comment: @userunknown das ist richtig. Ich habe bei der Formulierung mein Gegenbeispiel wohl wieder raus editiert. Belassen wir es beim allgemeinen Hinweis dass die Wörter nicht immer und überall ersetzt werden können.

Answer (score 0):

Soweit *Folge* als Bestandteil den beiden Worten, *Reihenfolge* und *Abfolge*, gemein ist, gibt es natürlich Überschneidungen.

### Der Gebrauch von *Abfolge* ist aber recht eingeschränkt im Gegensatz zu *Reihenfolge*. Ein Blick in den Duden dürfte weiterhelfen. (Der Onus liegt aber beim Fragesteller).

Wegen *ab* "weg, herunter" will ich meinen, dass a) die Ordnung nicht zeitgleich, sondern **nacheinander**, *abtretend, abgehend, Abgang, Abbruch*, eben in Abfolge auftritt; Man sagt "etwas tritt in schneller Abfolge auf", ansonsten ist mir das Wort kaum geläufig, b) dass es neben *Abhandlung*, *abzählen* und *Aufzählung* so wirkt als sei die Abfolge *nach unten hin beschränkt*, sich einem Ende nähernd, c) dass daher eigentlich *subsequent* (nachrangig, nachgeordnet), nicht jedoch *subsequence* (mathematisch *Teilmenge einer Folge*), die passende Übersetzung sein müsste. Zwar hat *ab* noch weitere Deutungen, doch die oberflächliche Zerlegung in Einzelteile erschließt nicht den modernen Sprachgebrauch. Beispiele der Verwendung sind einfach zu googeln. Ich setze vorraus, das sei nicht mehr teil der Frage.

Reihenfolge dagegen bezeichnet all das, was in einer Reihe, zuweilen in einer gedachten Reihe, in irgendeiner sinnvoll geordneten Folge steht. Man sagt auch kurz *in Reihe*, was stark an das Militär *in Reih' und Glied* (s.a. *Riege*) erinnert, aber auch an eine Buchreihe geordnet als Reihe in den Fächern einer Regalreihe. Die Herkunft von *Reihe* ist ungewiss. Insofern könnte *rein, herein* "in, into" verglichen werden, was zwar absurd wirkt, aber doch naheliegt, soweit es im Gegensatz zu *ab-* (siehe oben) steht. Weiter wäre *rect-, recht, errichten* neben *Auf-Stellung* zusehen, sowie *Aufstellung* bspw. im Sport die taktische Angriffsformation, kurz *Stellung*, der Spieler beschreibt; Dabei spricht man auch von *auflaufen*, und der Reihenfolge in der die Spieler auf das Spielfeld laufen, vom Torwart am einen Ende bis zum Stürmer am anderen, wobei deutlich wird, dass die Spieler **zeitgleich nebeneinander *stehen***. Im wesentlichen wird eine *Hierarchie* beschrieben. Man spricht bürokratisch auch von der *Rangfolge*; Vgl. *Ranke* "vertikal erstrecktes Gewächs*, sinnbildlich *die Stufen einer Leiter*, sowie am ehesten En. *chain of command*, und daher *in Verbindung stehen* (vgl. deshalb *Serie*, Lat *ser-* "bind-"). En. *row* "Reihe" dagegen klingt als wäre das Rudern, *to row*, ausschlaggebend, sowie Ruderer auf langenen Reisen abwechseln müssen, dürfte aber aus dem Skandinavischen stammen und das Deutsche kaum erklären, zumal es sich um echte Homophone handelt. Nicht zuletzt wäre noch der *Rechen*, En. "rake", bzw. *rechnen* zu erwähnen, gesetzt den Fall dass eigentlich Muster gemeint sind, wie sie sich beim Harken, bzw. algorithmisch beim berechnen einzelner Schritte ergeben; So steht *Aufstellung* (siehe oben) auch für eine gestaffelte Rechnung, eine *Gegenüberstellung* von Kosten und Nutzen, Einnahmen und Ausgaben, usw.

Genaues weiß man eben nicht, umsomehr Spekulation ist nötig. Ein Zusammenhang ergibt sich aus der obigen Betrachtung leider nicht. Pfeiffer leitet [Reihe](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Reihe) versuchsweise zurück auf Indo-Germansich (Indo-Europäisch): "ie. *reik(h)-, eine Erweiterung der Wurzel ie. *rei- ‘ritzen, reißen, schneiden’"; *Reihenfolge* wird demnach als einfache Ableitung gesehen. Das hilft für die Deutung natürlich kaum weitef. *Folge* selbst ist ebenso interessant, soweit ungeklärt, wegen *Gefolge* oft mit *Volk*, *pleo-* "viel, füllen" verglichen worden; Vgl. deswegen *Erfüllung* vs *Erfolg*.

Jedenfalls wird wie eingangs erwähnt *-Folge* in viellerlei Ausdrücken zusammengesetzt mit thematischen Stämmen, *Redefolge, Schichtfolge, Programmfolge, Nachfolge, ...* etc. etc. Dabei hat *Reihenfolge* den Stamm *Folge* beinahe subsumiert, so dass gleichbedeutend *Programm-Reihenfolge* gebildet werden kann. Die *Programm-Abfolge* wäre dagegen eher synonym mit dem *Programm-Ablauf*.

PS: Auch der *Programm-Verlauf* findet sich, hat aber wie der *Flussverlauf*, bzw. eher *Flusslauf*, etwas willkürlich passives, unbeeinflusst von willentlicher Anordnung, so wie der Zuschauer keinen Einfluss darauf nehmen kann. Nur soweit am Lauf eines Flusses künstlich Veränderungen vorgenommen werden, wäre von einem *Verlauf* zu sprechen. Diese Unterscheidung gilt aber allgemeinhin nicht (nicht mehr?), zumal *sich verlaufen* entgegensteht mit einem negativen Unterton des Unwillkürlichen.